# Python: how to add remaining list elements to list, similar to unpack?

Tags: python, list, unpack

I have a list, which can have different size but it always have 1st item. I writing such comprehension:

```
return {
    'index': [[i[0][7:], i[1], i[2], i[3]] for i in columns if i[0].startswith("index::")]
}
```

And part `i[1], i[2], i[3]` could vary. It can have 0 or more size and I need to specify them as list elements.

Something like

```
return {
    'index': [[i[0][7:], *i[1:]] for i in columns if i[0].startswith("index::")]
}
```

would be great.

Input:

```
[['index::test', '1', '2', '3']]
[['index::test', '1', '2', '3', '5']]
[['index::test']]
```

Output:

```
[['index', '1', '2', '3']]
[['index', '1', '2', '3', '5']]
[['index']]
```

Comment: please post sample input and output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to use `[i[0][7:]] + i[1:]`.

Comment: At your example first part is string, second is list. It will produce an error. I want to modify first item and leave everything else unchanged.

Comment: Then do `[i[0][7:]] + i[1:]` .

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thank you for the input/output data.
Then, as BrenBarn and Anand S Kumar have suggested

```
return {
        'index': [[i[0][7:]]+i[1:]] for i in columns if i[0].startswith("index::")]
}
```